# Is it safe/possible to access virtual methods across a DLL boundary?

Tags: c++, c++11, dll, virtual-functions

Is a virtual function table safe or even possible to access across a dll boundary?

Application and dll (compiled from elsewhere) know of BaseClass, but only dll knows of the additional SuperClass that overrides the virtual methods.

If the dll provides a pointer to SuperClass to the application, can the application safely accesses and perform the correct methods (I.E. will call the SuperClass overridden method)?

Comment: probably only if you use the same compiler and runtime library.

Comment: By same compiler do you mean like the difference between MSVC 14 vs 15 or even to the exact minor version?

Comment: I've done that.  The only caveat I've run into is the need to avoid ODR violations and avoid ABI differences.  Build everything with the same compiler flags, using the same compiler and you should be good.

Comment: This is exactly how Direct-X works (COM interface).. it provides you with a pointer to an interface and you use that interface's functions.. same with JNI.. So it is indeed safe. This is also how MS-Detour Direct-X hooks work when hooking the vtable.

Comment: Sounds very fragile for what I have in mind though.  A plugin system for users to compile their own dll's to load in the application.  From what you are saying the base lib version that contains this API/SDK info does not change it should be fine, but the caveat of compiler differences makes me nervous.  Does that mean the approach is wrong? (posted before Brandon's comment was known)

Comment: Under Windows, all reasonable C++ compilers generate the same ABI for interfaces, i.e. classes containing no data and not using virtual inheritance. This is because COM, a key technology of Windows, is basically specified as "what our compiler does for such interfaces", and all compilers want to match that. So you can *really* rely on it working. But don't throw exceptions across the boundary, and don't use anything more complicated than an all-public struct in the parameter types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical vtable implementation is something a bit like this.

```
struct bob;
struct bob_vtable {
  void(*speak)(bob*) = 0;
};
struct bob {
  static void populate_vtable(bob_vtable* v){
    v->speak = bob::speak_impl;
  }
  static bob_vtable make_vtable(){
    bob_vtable vtable;
    populate_vtable(&vtable);
    return vtable;
  }
  bob_vtable const* get_vtable() {
    static const bob_vtable vtable = make_vtable();
    return &vtable;
  }
  static void speak_impl(bob* self){
    std::cout << self->name;
  }
  bob_vtable const* vtable=0;
  void speak(){
    vtable->speak(this);
  }
  bob():bob(get_vtable()){}
  bob(bob_vtable const* ptable){
    vtable=ptable;
  }
  std::string name="bob";
};

struct alice;
struct alice_vtable : bob_vtable {
  // new virtual methods in alice go here
  bool (*is_alice)(alice const*) = 0;
};
struct alice:bob{
  static void speak_impl(bob* bself){
    alice* self = static_cast<alice*>(bself);
    std::cout << "alice is not " << self->name;
  }
  static bool is_alice_impl(alice const*) {
    return true;
  }
  bool is_alice() const {
    return static_cast<alice_vtable const*>(vtable)->is_alice(this);
  }
  
  static void populate_vtable(alice_vtable* table){
    bob::populate_vtable(table);
    table->speak=alice::speak_impl; // this is an override of a bob_vtable method
    table->is_alice=alice::is_alice_impl; // new virtual method
  }
  static alice_vtable make_vtable(){
    alice_vtable vtable;
    populate_vtable(&vtable);
    return vtable;
  }
  alice_vtable const* get_vtable() {
    static const alice_vtable vtable = make_vtable();
    return &vtable;
  }
  alice():alice(get_vtable()){}
  alice(alice_vtable const* ptable):bob(ptable){
  }
};

struct charlie;
struct charlie_vtable : alice_vtable {};
struct charlie:alice {
  static bool is_alice_impl(alice const*) {
    return false;
  }
  static void populate_vtable(charlie_vtable* table){
    alice::populate_vtable(table);
    table->is_alice=charlie::is_alice_impl; // this is an override of a alice_vtable method
    // speak is left unoverloaded
  }
  static charlie_vtable make_vtable(){
    charlie_vtable vtable;
    populate_vtable(&vtable);
    return vtable;
  }
  charlie_vtable const* get_vtable() {
    static const charlie_vtable vtable = make_vtable();
    return &vtable;
  }
  charlie():charlie(get_vtable()){}
  charlie(charlie_vtable const* ptable):alice(ptable){
  }
};
```

Someone with a `bob*` doesn't have to know the object is an `alice`.  The `bob::speak` code looks at the vtable and finds the pointer to `alice::speak_impl` stored there at alice creation.

Compilers figure out how to call virtual methods because they agree on the *layout* of the object and its virtual function table.  Agreement on these layouts is far, far, far better than most other inter-compiler agreements.

```
void speak_as_bob( bob& b ) {
    b.speak();
}
int main() {
    bob b;
    alice a;
    speak_as_bob(b);
    std::cout << "\n";
    speak_as_bob(a);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

An important fact, however, is that the vtable for `alice` usually lives in the DLL that `alice` is defined in.  Those pointers can dangle if your unload the DLL before you call the function.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c32a509981f099c).

Output is

> ```
> bob
> alice is not bob
> ```

The function `speak_as_bob` has **no idea** about the vtable stuff we did.  It just calls `bob::speak()` on a reference to a `bob` object.  That completely normal method then looks up `bob_vtable::speak` and invokes it.

By default, creating a `bob` populated `bob::vtable->speak` with a pointer to `speak_impl`.  When we inherit an `alice`, we first construct a `bob` (with a pointer to `bob::speak_impl` in its vtable), then we override the field in `alice::populate_vtable` with a pointer to `alice::speak_impl` instead.

Prior to C++, people wrote object oriented code in C in a way similar to what I wrote above (but without methods, so you'd use free functions).  There are many ways to implement object oriented languages; C++'s virtual function is based around a design like the above.

Now there are some practical versioning issues.  I will speak to windows, because I know the issues there better.

If your *interface* changes from one DLL version to another, the virtual function table entries move, and the client who doesn't recompile dies a horrible death.

However, if you do virtual inheritance as well as virtual functions, each of the virtual interfaces you inherit from is a separate table, and you can add to the end of each.  (I do not know the layout of a virtual function table that involves virtual inheritance off hand, but it is more complex than the above example).

The order that windows compilers population vtables it the order of declaration of the methods, [b]unless[/b] you override a method; the overrides are clumped together.  If you want ABI stability over DLL versions so clients don't have to recompile, don't overload virtual methods.

Now, if you don't change the interface layout, you are sitting pretty.

Finally, I have found that the details of how dynamic libraries are loaded/unloaded on MacOS makes dynamic library lifetime a bit harder to navigate.  Following dead vtable pointers and crashing at shutdown doesn't happen nearly as often on windows as it does on macOS.  I am not certain why, possibly because windows does static destruction everywhere before it unloads the code, while macos does static destruction in a DLL, then unloads it immediately, before proceeding onto another DLL.

---

I also added a `charlie` so you can see how new methods can be added part way down the hierarchy.  Now, in real C++, the vtable pointer is assigned to `bob`'s vtable during `bob`'s construction, then reassigned to `alice`'s during `alice`'s construction, etc.  Here, we only set it to `alice`'s vtable to make things simpler.

The temporary "you are a `bob` during `bob` construction" means that methods that rely on `alice` constructor perquisites aren't accidentally called.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as the DLL is not unloaded while any SuperClass objects are instantiated. As far as the application is concerned, the object it is working with is a BaseClass object.

Comment: And to clarify that means application will call the SuperClass override of the method?

Comment: @Klypto Yup. I've used this technique (virtual functions) to avoid having to export lots of those member functions.